Thingsbaoard Gateway cannot update attributes from server
I am working with gateway and I am facing an issue related to attributes and RPC. At a minimum fixing attributes would be ok. I has been over 2 weeks trying to install and setup, but no success so far.
I can send telemetry and dynamically create devices into TB server. But updating a shared attribute on TB dashboard throws this error message on GW logs.
|ERROR| - [mqtt_connector.py] - mqtt_connector - on_attributes_update - 799 - Cannot find attributeName by filter in message with data: {'device': '1234567890', 'data': {'pin0': False, 'fwStateIsSynced': False}}
my mqtt.json config looks as follow in the relevan part ...
"attributeRequests": [{"retain": false,"topicFilter": "v1/devices/me/attributes/request","deviceInfo": {"deviceNameExpressionSource": "message","deviceNameExpression": "${serialNumber}"},"attributeNameExpressionSource": "message","attributeNameExpression": "pin0","topicExpression": "devices/${deviceName}/attrs","valueExpression": "${attributeKey}: ${attributeValue}"}],"attributeUpdates": [{"retain": true,"deviceNameFilter": ".*","attributeFilter": "pin0","topicExpression": "sensor/${deviceName}/${attributeKey}","valueExpression": "{"${attributeKey}":"${attributeValue}"}"}]

I've tried many different options but no success so far. i.e. like deviceNameJsonExpression or attributeNameJsonExpression : "${pin0}" but the result is mostly the same... cannot update the attribs Thingsboard Server 3.7.0 Thingsboard Gateway 3.5.1 - Docker compse version Client RPi mqtt nodered simulated
